# После добавления поля в таблицу с помощью миграции в тестах(codecept unit) выпадает ошибка Setting unknown property

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2, frontend, codeception

Yii2. После добавления поля в таблицу с помощью миграции в тестах(codecept unit) выпадает ошибка Setting unknown property: mommon\entities\User::email_confirm_token на класс, наследующий ActiveRecord. Кэш обнулял, само приложение работает нормально. 
PhpStorm тоже ругается, что поле не используется(после его определения в Phpdoc), хотя используется в методах и они работают.

Answer (score 0):

Забыл применить миграцию на тестовой бд.